# Ubuntu 20.04 upgraded some network-manager packages, now problems are ensuing

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, 20.04, network-manager

First of all, these issues only started on 20.04 after a recent network-manager upgrade (and the related components such as network-manager-gnome) and this is a laptop, HP envy m7-n101dx running 20.04. I have tried disabling power management on the device via two commands (I didn't write them down) given to me from someone on IRC. They essentially disabled power management for Wireless. Before that I was getting disconnected and had to manually reconnect to get back online. At least it's not permanent or requiring a reboot every time. I ran the command sudo lshw -C network and I apparently have an Intel Wireless 7265 card. I know these are plaguing users of the forums with issues related to their power management. But the real issue is recently it disconnected right after startup. Literally seconds after logging and directly from cold boot and the boot screen, instant disconnect. These issues have never happened on older releases or packages on this laptop. And it was gone for a while, so I was hoping it was done for. Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it? For a more detailed look at the command output, see below:
Output of sudo lshw -C network: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B5dFjqJhh6/

This has literally been copy pasted from the forums as I don't think many people use the forums as much anymore. Not to be pushy, but to ensure somebody sees my message.

I also ran more commands from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108).

The output is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QtjTbrVj9d/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reviewing your paste, we see:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Mike L Network-5GHz' [AC1]>
                    Channel:44
                    Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Mike L Network-5GHz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000226e172381
                    Extra: Last beacon: 120ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Your router is set to channel 44 where there are also four other competing access points. Your wireless card also is capable of many other channels:

```
      Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
      Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
      Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
      Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
      Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
      Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
      Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
      Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
      Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
      Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
      Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
      Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
      Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
      Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
      Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
      Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
      Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
      Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
      Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
```

I recommend that you set your router to another fixed channel, not autoselect, away from the already crowded channel 44.

Next, the name of the SSID is Mike L Network-5GHz. I have worked on several cases where spaces in the name interfered with solid, consistent connection. I suggest that you rename the router to MikeLNetwork5 or some such without any spaces. I'd similarly rename the 2.4 GHz segment, as well. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Well, I've renamed the networks, and changed the country code from unset to US. I've also changed away from that crowded channel. I guess most people don't bother to change it. Thanks. Now it may take days for the difference to be seen. But only this Ubuntu laptop was disconnecting. S10+ phone and Raspberry Pi were fine. Still a bit uneasy.

Comment: A week later and that multi pronged approach may have done it. Thank you! I will leave this open until a month has passed, then mark the above as the answer if everything keeps behaving.